# How to refresh a layout preview in Android Studio "Iguana"?

Tags: android-studio

Before the new version of Android Studio codenamed "Iguana", one could refresh a layout preview simply by giving focus to the outer edge of the preview and pressing <kbd>R</kbd>. In this new version, that does not work anymore (i.e. a loading bar would appear on the very bottom saying "Refreshing layout"). Perhaps there is an alternate way to do this without having to build the whole module?[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with the AVDs that I created before this new update. The solution that worked for me was either to use the "wipe data" option for the existing AVDs or to create a new AVD from scratch.

Update: These solutions only work temporarily. The screen refresh issue persists after a few minutes. Therefore, there's no solution on my end.

Update 2: I strongly recommend reverting to the Hedgehog version from the Iguana version, as the latter seems to be unstable.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to enable "Live updates" for Compose preview so you don't even need to press R to refresh the preview.

You can enable this flag from the Android Studio settings at:
`Editor` -> `Design tools` -> `Compose Preview` section -> `Enable live updates`

hope this helps